# ¿El o la app? ¿Un o una app?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, género, artículos, terminología

[La recomendación de la Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/aplicacion-alternativa-a-app/) es no abreviar y usar «aplicación» o, si se quiere abreviar, hacerlo de una forma más ¿española? y abreviarlo como «apli».

Sin embargo es «app» lo que se sigue usando en la lengua corriente, así que, hasta que nos hayamos adaptado a las recomendaciones de la Fundéu, ¿cuáles os parece que deben ser los determinantes para «app»?

Aunque partamos de la base de que es una palabra femenina (por su traducción al español, no porque en inglés lo sea), no deja de ser una palabra que empieza por /a/ tónica. ¿Debería seguir el patrón de «el agua»? [Las únicas excepciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustantivos_femeninos_que_empiezan_por_a-_o_ha-_t%C3%B3nicas) al cambio de artículo son los nombres propios (y no todos) y los nombres de letras, condiciones que «app» no cumple. Tampoco he podido encontrar otros monosílabos comenzados por /a/ para comparar: «aj», «as» y «haz» son masculinos, y no parece que haya más, a no ser que se me escape algo.

Las búsquedas de Google no ayudan mucho puesto que, aunque es innegable que el [artículo «la» es el preferido](https://www.google.es/trends/explore#q=el%20app%2C%20la%20app%2C%20un%20app%2C%20una%20app&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-1), la preferencia se invierte con el indeterminado «un» sobre «una».

¿Debería aceptarse que el artículo femenino se ha asentado como norma *de facto* para «app»? ¿O debería respetarse la norma del cambio de artículo? ¿Ideas? ¿Se me ha pasado algo por alto?

Comment: Nunca jamás he visto una aplicación referida como "apli" en español, y siempre en femenino, como en _la aplicación_.

Comment: Hay otro ejemplo que quiero comentar. APA (Asociación de Padres de Alumnos) y AMPA. Siempre he oído la APA y las APAS. No tengo una fuente escrita, pero parece ser otro caso en que el género de la palabra sin apocopar permanece en la palabra apocopada o en las siglas. Del mismo modo que comentó Melisa según el DPD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Es *una aplicación* (en femenino).

La definición y la explicación vienen de hace años, cuando aún no existía el *boom* que ha sufrido el mundo de la telefonía y del desarrollo web y de aplicaciones. Según el Diccionario de la Real Academia Española (DRAE):

> **Aplicación**
>
> Del lat. *applicatio*, *-ōnis*.
>
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de aplicar o aplicarse.
> 2. f. Afición y asiduidad con que se hace algo, especialmente el estudio.
> 3. f. Ornamentación ejecutada en materia distinta de otra a la cual se sobrepone.
> 4. f. Inform. Programa preparado para una utilización específica, como el pago de nóminas, el tratamiento de textos, etc.
> 5. f. Mat. Operación por la que se hace corresponder a todo elemento de un >conjunto un solo elemento de otro conjunto.

Es decir, antes de usar el término aplicación a cualquier programa web o para *smartphone*, la palabra ya existía y se usaba en femenino. Actualmente se ha acomodado dicha palabra a los nuevos significados que adquiere, pero sin cambiar el género.

En el caso de usar la abreviación *app*, la explicación sigue siendo la misma, ya que aplicación y *app* se refieren al mismo concepto, y por tanto el género se mantiene invariable.

Comment: Gracias, aunque mi pregunta iba más orientada a la abreviación «app» y al artículo que debe acompañarla, que normalmente se cambia al masculino cuando una palabra femenina empieza por /a/ tónica. «Agua» también es femenino, pero es «el agua, un agua». Sobre «aplicación» sin abreviar no hay ninguna duda. Quizás no me he expresado bien.

Comment: Quizá no me haya explicado correctamente. La abreviación de aplicación a app no varia el significado, ya que se refieren a la misma palabra. Una aplicación se traduce a una app. En el caso que usas de agua, está mal: sigue siendo una agua, pero la existencia de dos letras iguales seguidas hace que al pronunciarla se omitan y dé la sensación que una no existe. Espero que haya aclarado un poco las dudas @guillem

Comment: Tienes razón en que con un/una + /a/ tónica hay vacilación en el femenino, pero mi pregunta sigue en pie para el artículo determinado.

Comment: He editado la respuesta. App sigue manteniendo el género de su palabra original, femenino, por lo que app lleva delante una/s o la/s. @guillem

Comment: Sigo sin entender muy bien el razonamiento. ¿Qué hace que no le aplique esta norma? http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=8Tu5qHMtQD63wEn6zW

Comment: Porqué app viene de aplicación, cuya tónica está en la O (por eso lleva tilde) y no en la A inicial. Para seguir las reglas sintácticas te tienes que basar en la palabra aplicación, no en app, ya que en castellano aún no se ha aceptado @guillem

Comment: Entiendo que la norma es por eufonía y que debería (eso ya es opinión mía) basarse en la palabra misma. De otro modo, si más adelante se aceptase (¿quién?) nos veríamos en la tesitura de que de repente sí le aplica una norma que antes no le aplicaba.

Comment: La aceptaria la RAE (Real Academia de la lengua Española). El diccionario se adapta a los nuevos tiempos, de manera que si una o varias palabras están muy de moda, o son de la orden del día, se añaden al diccionario y se les aplica las normas gramaticales y sintácticas correspondientes, hasta entonces, son abreviaciones o palabras que derivan de otras (como app por ejemplo). Adjunto un link de las últimas palabras añadidas por la RAE estos últimos años. http://noticias.universia.es/cultura/noticia/2014/10/23/1113700/nuevas-palabras-aprobadas-rae.html

Comment: ¿Significa eso que si mañana se recogiese «app» en el DRAE, la repetición del sonido /a'a/ al usarla con el artículo sería aceptable hasta entonces, pero no a partir de entonces?

Comment: No, significa que si mañana se aceptase app, se vería el modo en que dicha palabra se adapta a las normas existentes. De momento, al provenir de aplicación, sigue sus normas sintácticas y gramaticales. Por ejemplo, antes de aceptarse escáner, se usaba la palabra inglesa scanner; no tenía ningún tipo de sentido usar las normas de la lengua en una palabra de origen inglés. Al aceptarse, se adaptó la palabra, se le puso una E delante y se acentuó de acuerdo con las normas.

Comment: Tiene bastante sentido. Esperaré un día o dos por si salen más ideas, de lo contrario la daré como contestada.

Comment: I believe this to be the correct answer. However, in spoken spanish it is common to default to the masculine genero for pronouns who's referent are not yet in the context. I imagine this would apply to "app" too so you could use masculine genero.

Answer (score 6):

El mismo artículo de la Fundéu que citas te da la respuesta: si te fijas, en su recomendación escriben *una apli*, aun cuando *apli* empieza por a tónica.

El motivo es que usamos la misma forma de artículo que usaríamos en la palabra sin apocopar; puesto que *aplicación* es femenina y comienza por a átona, decimos *una aplicación* y, de ahí, *una apli*. Si preferimos usar el apócope inglés *app*, el mismo razonamiento nos lleva a *una app*.

Por cierto, no es demasiado raro escuchar alguna persona que pronuncia *una apepé*, como si *app* fueran las siglas de algo. Pero esto ya se va de la pregunta.

Comment: Es verdad, se me pasó completamente ese detalle del artículo de la Fundéu. Podría achacarlo a que la obligatoriedad está sólo en el artículo determinado, pero no sé si estaría ya yendo contra el principio de simplicidad en mi sesgo por el masculino.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún ejemplo de otra palabra femenina que comience con *a-* y que, al apocoparse, traslade el acento a la primera sílaba sin emplear el artículo femenino alternativo *el* (es decir, sigue usando la forma femenina normal *la*)?

Comment: @guifa Me temo que no; al fin y al cabo, tampoco hay tantas palabras que se apocopen habitualmente en español. El DPD no dice nada sobre este caso concreto, pero sí habla de un caso parecido: siglas que comienzan por a tónica, pero cuya primera palabra original es femenina que empieza por a átona. Y en ese caso dice que se usa *la* y no *el*: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=8Tu5qHMtQD63wEn6zW#23

Answer (score 5):

Deberíamos tratar a esta palabra («app») como tratamos a las palabras «agua», «alma» y «hacha», que son sustantivos *femeninos* que por su **/a/ tónica** deben cambiar de género para el artículo definido e indefinido.

Véase:

_ agua (f.): ***el*** agua, *las* aguas; ***un*** agua, *unas* aguas; *esta* agua, *estas* aguas.

_ alma (f.): ***el*** alma, *las* almas; ***un*** alma, *unas* almas; *esta* alma, *estas* almas.

_ hacha (f.): ***el*** hacha, *las* hachas; ***un*** hacha, *unas* hachas; *esta* hacha, *estas* hachas.

Entonces:

_ app (f., de «aplicación»): ***el*** app, *las* apps; ***un*** app, *unas* apps; *esta* app, *estas* apps.

p. ej. Debo buscar *un* app en *el* App Store, quiero actualizar *las* apps...

Comment: pues no conozco nadie que le diga el App Store, siempre he oído que le dicen LA app store, pues porque es la tienda

Answer (score 4):

Entiendo que APP es una abreviación por proceso de acortamiento de la palabra aplicación, ortográficamente mal escrita por que no debería llevar la doble p, pero desde el punto de vista gramatical le caben las reglas propias de este procedimiento de abreviación; que según el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=YCD8S5n6nD6NMUUtBY) serían:

> **acortamiento**. 1. Procedimiento de abreviación que consiste en eliminar las sílabas finales de una palabra para crear otra nueva: bici por bicicleta, cine por cinematógrafo, profe por profesor, súper por supermercado, macro por macroinstrucción, moto por motocicleta, foto por fotografía, taxi por taxímetro, etc. También existen, aunque en menor número, casos de acortamiento por supresión de sílabas iniciales: bus por autobús, fago por bacteriófago.
>   2. La mayoría de los acortamientos mantienen el género de la palabra completa: la foto por la fotografía, el cine por el cinematógrafo; hay alguna excepción, como el cromo por la cromolitografía. Los acortamientos, cuando son sustantivos, suelen seguir las reglas generales de formación del plural (→ plural, 1): las fotos, las anfetas, los buses; pero algunos de ellos, como súper e híper, se mantienen invariables: los híper, los súper. Cuando son adjetivos, lo normal es que permanezcan invariables: películas porno (‘pornográficas’).

Por lo tanto, el artículo que le corresponde es `la` y su plural sería `Apps`.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece lo correcto es "el app".

En [¿El iPad? ¿la Xbox? ¿el app? ¿cómo se dice en español?](https://www.cnet.com/es/noticias/el-ipad-la-xbox-el-app-como-se-dice-en-espanol/) se comenta:

> (...) Todo eso nos lleva a las 'apps', que por ahí también insisten en llamarles los 'apps'. Por supuesto que no soy lingüista, pero a mí me gusta la idea de mantener el femenino cuando se trata de una abreviatura de una palabra en femenino, pues (la aplicación). Pero volvemos al mismo tema de "la agua". "La app de tal cosa" suena mal; así que mejor quedarnos con el app.

Y en [la discusión "el / la App" en Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/el-la-app.2222978/?hl=es) leo:

> APP = application (en inglés), entonces en castellano es una aplicación pero, como dice Alisterio, es el/un APP y unas APPs.

o

> He leído y escuchado a algunas personas referirse a "el aplicativo", en cuyo caso, la forma corta sí sería "el app".

Aunque veo en distintos blogs se usa indistinto.

Comment: Sería mejor incluir el contenido relevante en esta respuesta. Si la página enlazada deja de existir, esta respuesta no contendría nada. Es mejor evitar respuestas tipo "aquí hay un link, que la gente se lo lea y saque conclusiones".

Comment: @Diego totalmente de acuerdo. Desgraciadamente, estos usuarios no registrados casi nunca vuelven para editar la pregunta, por lo que o bien la editamos nosotros o bien la borramos. ¿Qué te parece que podríamos hacer en este caso?

Comment: @fedorqui, buena pregunta, casi que podría discutirse en meta. Yo estos días tengo menos tiempo para participar por aquí, si no me animaría y la editaría yo. En cualquier caso, tal y como está entendería si alguien la marcase para ser borrada, ya que es poco más que un link. Creo que lo mejor sería si alguien quisiera "parasitar" el "esfuerzo" de los usuarios que postean solo un link escribiendo una respuesta (quizá community wiki?) que incluya el contenido relevante del link. Yo tampoco obligaría a que fuese CW, ya que los _upvotes_ serían la "recompensa" por el esfuerzo de hacer de editor.

Comment: @Diego DGaleano planteó [Should we allow unregistered users to answer questions?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2473/1674) y cada vez tiendo a estar más de acuerdo, pues estas publicaciones no nos hacen demasiado bien al trasladar un mensaje incorrecto sobre qué tipo de respuestas queremos. Me gusta la idea que comentas, que yo directamente convertiría en: publicar una respuesta nueva en base al enlace proporcionado, para valorar más activamente el esfuerzo del usuario que acaba haciendo un buen redactado.

Answer (score 1):

Estaba por publicar esto como comentario, pero siendo una de mis controversias mascota, (pet peeve) les comparto mi opinión:

De hecho todo el concepto informático de "**aplicación**" es erróneo por la traducción como falso amigo de *application*.

---

EL concepto de informática que se alinea más de cerca con el concepto original en inglés de *application*, es el casi arcaico y ochentero **paquete** en castellano.

Alternativamente, y estirando un poco la definición podríamos usar como sustantivos apropiado el castizo y trillado **programa**

Se estira el significado ya que es rarisimo encontrar una **solución informática** que conste de in solo programa monolítico, de ahí que el **paquete** (de programas) sea más apropiado.

Ambos sustantivos (paquete/programa)  se pueden *aplicar* a la solución de un problema, siendo el adverbio *aplicación* el proceso de solución apoyado por el antemencionado **programa/paquete de programas**.

> En resumen: lo más preciso, y conservador es ***evitar el neologismo app*** y sus adicionales problemas de redacción y usar el auténtico concepto equivalente: ***paquete /programa***

---

Debemos notar que en inglés, se usaba *package* y *program*, y más usualmente *software* de donde se hizo sinonimia *package* y *application software*.

Todo el furor de las *"app"* viene de un ingenioso  **juego de palabras con fines mercadotecnicos** uno de los retoños tardíos de la genialidad de ***Steve Jobs*** quien invirtió una cantidad ridícula de dinero para poder quitarle el sufijo *"Inc."* (incorporada) a su compañía para que se llamara sencilla y llanamente "**Apple**" (los derechos de esta marca, pertenecían a la disquera que conserva los derechos sobre el catálogo de los Beatles, *Apple records*); y es por ello que irónicamente no se podía adquirir música de los Beatles en iTunes sino hasta recientemente.

Volviendo al tema, se hace evidente el objetivo de impulsar el genérico. *"App"* como sinónimo de **paquete / programa** :

> Las computadoras PC de los mortales sólo pueden correr programas. Necesitas un equipo **App**le para poder ejecutar un **App**
>
> *Apple: the app company. There is an app for that.*

Comment: Una perspectiva interesante, por ser totalmente diferente, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo la forma adecuada debe ser siempre en femenino la app. De aplicación, y frecuentemente por falta de conocimiento, hay personas que no tienen ni idea que el abreviado app es precisamente ( aplicación ) no obstante mucha gente
acostumbra hablar de un "icono" para el móvil en masculino, modus operandi de la aplicación, saltándose el icono, pero conservando la articulación **el** app.

Comment: He eliminado el lenguaje condescenciente de la última frase de la respuesta. Las respuestas deben concentrarse únicamente en responder a la pregunta. Más información en [answer] y en el [Código de Conducta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/conduct).